# overwritten files with nothing in python script

Tags: python, data-recovery

I have overwritten some files with nothing (0 Bytes) with a python script. I did that by confusing the input and output file path. Is there any way to recover the files?

Comment: Power the system off *IMMEDIATLY* and boot a live system - then you might have a chance with recovery software.

Comment: You probably want to remove mentions of python here - *how* it happened isn't relevant. Instead say what OS/filesystem etc you have as it's really a general data recovery question. That way you'll get potentially see more answers.